# Check if Set contains value - wrong type error

Tags: trigger, tasks

This is a trigger on the task object. I am trying to see if the task being deleted is one the of record types in my set. I am getting an error. I have to create this as Salesforce won't give us the ability to prevent task deletion.

Here is my code:

```
if(trigger.isdelete && trigger.isbefore){

        Set<RecordType> recType = new set<RecordType> ( [SELECT Id 
                                    FROM RecordType 
                                    WHERE (Name = 'Five9 Call' AND sobjecttype = 'Task') 
                                    OR (Name = 'Client Escalation Task' AND sobjecttype = 'TasK')]);

        String ProfileId = UserInfo.getProfileId();
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name= 'System Administrator']; 

        if(recType != NULL){

            for(Task tsk: trigger.old){

                //if(tsk.RecordTypeId == RecordTypeAid & ProfileId != p.Id){
                if( recType.contains(tsk.RecordTypeId) && ProfileId != p.Id){
                    tsk.addError('You are not permitted to delete this activity.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
Incompatible element type Id for collection of RecordType
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that you're trying to compare an SObject (RecordType) to a scalar value (Id), which you can't do.

Instead, you'll want the record type ID values in your set:

```
Set<Id> recordTypeIds = 
    new Map<Id, Record Type> ( [SELECT Id 
                           FROM RecordType 
                           WHERE (Name = 'Five9 Call' AND sobjecttype = 'Task') 
                           OR (Name = 'Client Escalation Task' AND sobjecttype = 'TasK')]).keySet();
```

Even better, you should probably just use describe calls to save a query:

```
Map<String, RecordTypeInfo> taskRecordTypes =
    Task.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName();
Set<Id> recordTypeIds = new Set<Id> {
    taskRecordTypes.get('Five9 Call').getRecordTypeId(),
    taskRecordTypes.get('Client Escalation Task').getRecordTypeId()
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new Map<Id, RecordType([/*query*/]).keySet()`? Last I checked, `Set` does not have a `keySet` method.

Comment: @AdrianLarson lol. Yeah. Got ahead of myself. I'll fix it.

Comment: I used your first statement sfdcfox as I don't know how to use that map in my filter condition.

Comment: @MattM The second form doesn't need a RecordType query at all; you get the Id values directly from a describe call.

Comment: I understand that. I don't know how to use it in the IF statement to check if the task type being deleted is in that map. I tried taskRecordTypes.contains but it doesn't seem to support that.

Comment: @MattM `recordTypeIds.contains(tsk.RecordTypeId)` ... the describe part is just to get to the second part.